# Path does not exist Spark

Tags: spring, scala, apache-spark

I am implementing rest service using scala and spring and I  want to process the data in spark. Currently I have a method

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/csv"), method = Array(POST))
def handleCsvFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") file: MultipartFile) = {
println(file.getOriginalFilename)
val procedurePerformed = SparkConfig.sc.read.format("csv")
  .schema(TableSchema.getProcedurePermormedSchema()).option("header", "false")
  .csv(file.getOriginalFilename)

procedurePerformed.show()

new ResponseEntity[String]("Processing Complete", HttpStatus.OK)
```

}

And here is spark config

```
val fileUrl = "file:///${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse/"

val sc = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("API")
.master("local[6]")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", fileUrl)
.config("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", true)
.config("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize", 10000)
.getOrCreate()
```

But Spark throwing the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/D:/eclipse/procedure_performed.csv;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSource.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:252)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:342)
at org.fl.api.controllers.HomeController.handleCsvFileUpload(HomeController.scala:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: is your files are available in D:/eclipse/procedure_performed.csv location?

Comment: No it is not.  I only want to load file from MultipartFile (object) parameter which is coming in post request body but I dont understand why spark is looking for  file at "D:/eclipse/procedure_performed.csv"

Comment: if its object file you need to use `sc.objectFile()` method